# Convert Angular Modal to Ajax Content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Based on the advice of the commenter below, I have changed my code to the following.  Content shows up but the controller does not load.

```
var profileContent = $('#profilePage');
profileContent.attr('ng-controller','contactsProfileController');
profileContent.load('/contacts/profile/');   
$compile(profileContent.contents())($scope);
```

Comment: You're not using the $compile function correctly. The second argument is a clone function. Here is the proper usage from angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage

Comment: So I use: $compile(profileContent.contents())($scope);  Which seems to be *more* correct but doesn't help get me any further.  Probably the real question is should I be using $compile for this?  It just seems like such a simple thing... but I'm missing something basic.

Comment: If you're pulling in the HTML from ajax, and it has directives, then $compile is necessary. How about creating a div with ng-controller attribute, populating it with the ajax contents, and then compiling the div: $compile(divWithAjaxContents)(scope); ?

Comment: I tried this but the controller doesn't load, my code is above..